# Different Set of Variables for IE using SASS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, sass

I was wondering if anyone has come up with an idea for how to include a different set of SASS variables in IE than in other browsers.

Essentially, I have a list of variable colors in a SASS sheet that I would like to change depending on whether the user is using IE. My client has noticed that our colors look fine on some monitors but on some monitors (usually IE users) they look washed out. So I would like to specify a slightly darker set of variables for IE users than everyone else.

Essentially I want this:

```
$black: #111;
$white: #efefef;
```

To look like this for IE:

```
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
```

I realize this may be a simple question but for the life of me I can't seem to find an answer. Any ideas or help on this would be great.

Comment: Off topic: I strongly suggest you convince your client this is a very bad idea that is doomed to failure. Clients need to be educated and informed when their seemingly bright idea can't work for technical reasons nobody has control over. This is wrong for so many reasons; e.g. branding rules and no monitor is the same — every monitor has a different color gamut, even on pcs.

Comment: I suggest that the clients adjust their monitors properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is a way to do this built in to SASS. This is because SASS compiles before there is any interaction with the user. However, what I WOULD do, is create an ie.scss file.

The first step would be to put all of your variable definitions in to a _variables.scss file. After that you could make a: _ie_variables.scss file.

Finally, your ie.scss file would be the same as your style.scss file, except that after importing your _variables.scss you would then also import your _ie_variables.scss.

You then would include it like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately the doubling of CSS file loads would really slow things down so I'm going to have to find another way to frame this problem. But again, thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to double load.. just use the one css for IE, and the other for everything else... NOTE: conditional comments are no longer supported in IE10, which will use the same mode as other browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Tracker1 Your extra nudge forced me to do some extra research to discover the <![if !IE]><![endif]> tag that allowed me to load separate CSS sheets depending on what browser it's in. Code now looks like this:

<!--[if IE]>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application_ie", :media => "all" %>
 <![endif]-->
 <![if !IE]>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
 <![endif]>